# How to show an option selected if formControlName values doesnot matches option value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I have a material dropdown that populates a list of Customer Names. Everything is working but just now while testing found a bug.

The bug may seem small but will affect the process in a large way. Let me elaborate on the situation:
There is a Customer Information Panel (in the admin panel) where I'm doing CRUD for the Customer Names. From there through an API the array of names are coming which is populating the dropdown.

On submit of the form from the name is submitted as `XYZ`, then after that if I delete this name from the admin side and I view from the form the name is not shown in the dropdown which is quiet natural but the name stays in the `formControlName`.

Now here is the scenario I need to show the formControlName data in dropdown as selected even when the data is not present in option (working fine when data in present in option value).

Here is my current code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Customer Name</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="customerName" (selectionChange)="custData($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerNames" [value]="customer.customerName">
      {{customer.customerName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error>Customer Name Required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

What extra condition do I need to give to solve the scenario?

This is the issue [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bf6jus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a new option

```html
    <select formControlName="option">
        <option *ngIf="optionList.indexOf(form.get('option').value)<0" 
             hidden [value]="form.get('option').value">
             {{form.get('option').value}}</option>
    
         <option *ngFor="let opt of optionList" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
    </select>
```

I added "hidden" so it's not selectable

**Updated** if we has a complex options is possible we need use an auxiliar getter (in this case I use directly a FormControl, the tecnica is the same if using a FormGroup, only remembre that we should use `myForm.get('nameOfControl')`

```
  get includeValue()
  {
    return this.foods.map(x=>x.value).indexOf(this.control.value)<0
  }

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="control">
    <mat-option *ngIf="includeValue" style="display:none" [value]="control.value">{{control.value}}</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2i8zg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.html)

Comment: this 1 working fine for normal but not in mat-select  can you suggest why

Comment: I updated the answer using a mat-select and an array of object. I suppose the problem you found is not display or if yu're using an array of object.

Comment: as you have done this normal form control it's ok but getting problem that while using ```formControlName``` instead of ```[formControl]``` this is throwing this error:
```TypeError: this.form.get(...) is null```. And what i have figured out is it's because ```formControlName``` is not inside box bracket i guess but also ```formControlName``` can't be inside box bracket . So any solution you can provide for this

Comment: I updated the stackblitz to add a second case with a FormGroup. See that you change the function `includeValue` - the formGroup use the function `includeValueInGroup`-. The last case is using a simple array of strings, there're no function "includeValue"

Comment: yup now working but I have a question why do we need to write like that instead of normal ```form.get('foo').value``` 

Comment: if your variable formGroup is called `form` and your control is called `foo` you write form.get('foo').value. in the example the form is called `form2` and the control `control`, but it's the same. Really, from Angular 9 you can write also `form.value.foo`, but as  little personal mania I usually use get

Comment: @Eliseo ,I have one question in regards to the angular material table can you please help here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an

Answer (score 0):

As you fetch data from the server and also want to show the selected name after deleting the options. In this situation, you can use `mat-autocomplete`.

I have updated your code for [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9gjffc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Or

you can use read-only input to show the `formControlName`. After selection, you need to hide the select field and bind the data with an input field. Also, add a click event on the input field to hide the input and show select.

Comment: The example link is not working can you please update it

Comment: The example link has updated. Please check out https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview for more info.